# Make point layer from attributes of polygon layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

How to make point layer from attributes of polygon layer?

I made two polygon vector layer and have given some attributes to them, after that I labelled them but some of labels from two layers are overlapping.  I tried different ways to label but it is not presentable if I place my labels away from center point. Label is shifting away from center point.

I want to label something like AutoCAD in which if some labels are overlapping I can move that specific label and other labels remains at same location.

So, I thought if I make point layer of labels then I can move them as I wish.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  You haven't supplied enough information.  Please [edit] your question to explain what exactly you're trying to do, and how you think it might be accomplished.  What have you tried?  Where you would like each point to be created - at the midpoint, or at each end?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: This is a broad question, but I bet using the Poygon centroids tool (Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon centroids) would get @nawnit 90% of the way toward his goal.

Comment: @mr.adam thanks
How can I do the same thing for line shape file

Answer (score 1):

With data-defined label placement, you can rearrange labels without creating a separate layer.

Step 1:  Add two decimal number fields to your attribute table. Name them something like LabelX and LabelY. Under Label Properties > Data Defined > Coordinate > set these fields to control your label's X and Y coordinates.[image: Setting Data Defined Coordinates]

Step 2:  Turn on the Label Toolbar. Use the Move Label tool to rearrange your labels. The layer will need to be in edit mode, because as you move the labels around the tool is editing the LabelX and LabelY attributes.

[image]